# how to make same idea of data-spy in bootstrap, only with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

in other words when I scroll the page the elements on navigation bar will change their background colour according to their sections on the page.
I came up with this code but it does not work. I can do it with jQuery,bootstrap but I need it with javascript, html and css only.
you can run the snippet to see how I need it to be.

```
window.onscroll = function() {ActiveNavBar()};
function ActiveNavBar() {
  var elPos = document.getElementById("topic").offsetTop;
  var scrollPos = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop;
    if (scrollPos >= elPos) {
      var v = document.getElementById("navbar-introduction");
      v.style.backgroundColor = "#868e96";
    } else {
      var v = document.getElementById("navbar-introduction");
        v.style.backgroundColor = null;
    }
    }
```

```html
  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Tax</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--google icons-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--google fonts-->
    <style>
      body {
        padding-top: 3.5rem;
        background-color: #f5f8fa;
        font-family:  Montserrat, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      }

      a.dropdown-toggle {
         outline: none
       }


        button.scroll-to-top{
          position: fixed;
          bottom: 0.5rem;
          right: 0.5rem;
          cursor: pointer;
          background-color: #3097D1;
        }

        .scroll-to-top {
          color: white;
        }


        nav.navbar-color {
          background-color: #3097D1;
               }

        img.card-img {
          opacity: 0.2;
        }

        a.active{
          background-color: #868e96;
        }


    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>

         window.onscroll = function() {
           scrollFunction()
         }
function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) { //refers to full standard mode som declared by <!doctype html>
      $("button.scroll-to-top").removeClass("d-none");
      $("scroll-to-top").addClass("d-inline");
    } else {
      $("button.scroll-to-top").removeClass("d-inline");
      $("button.scroll-to-top").addClass("d-none");
    }
}
function topFunction() {
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}


    </script>
  </head>
  <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
    <!--assistive technologies attributes should be used-->
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top rounded-0 navbar-dark navbar-color" role="navigation">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navigation" aria-label="toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">(menu button)</span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navigation"><!-- "show" can be used here and the aria-expand will be true-->
          <!--dont use d-flex its make dropdown expand automatic-->
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link rounded text-white text-center" href="#topic">example</a><!-- if active are used then area-selected="true"-->
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link rounded text-white text-center" href="#introduction">example</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link rounded text-white text-center" href="#proposal"> example</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main role="main">
      <div class="card topic text-white text-center mx-auto rounded-0 py-5 bg-dark" id="topic" data-offset="50">
        <div class="card-body">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container py-5"  id="introduction">
        <div class="row py-5 justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center py-5">
          <div class="col-md-10">
        </div>
      </div>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="row pt-5 justify-content-center" id="proposal">
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-10">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-10">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row pt-5 justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="container">
      <hr class="my-4">
    </footer>
    <button onclick="topFunction()" type="button" class="btn d-none scroll-to-top">
      <span class="sr-only">(scroll to top button)</span>
      <i class="material-icons align-middle item-light">keyboard_arrow_up</i><!--only on Chrome-->
    </button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="logout" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="logoutdocument" aria-hidden="true"><!--tabindex to make the content focusable to force voiceover to not skip the content due to some browser like safari-->
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header card-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="logoutdocument">Are you sure you want to leave us ?</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close close-button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">If you are ready to leave this page please select "LogOut"
          </div>
          <div class="ml-auto mb-2 mt-3 mr-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <a  class="btn btn-secondary" href="signin.html">LogOut</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="javascript.util.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want to make navbar transparent  when scrolled down ,right?

Comment: no i want to change background color to the elements on navbar according to position to each one on the page.

Comment: are you using jquery ?i think i have solution in jquery

Comment: I know how to do it in jquery :) I need it with javascript only

Comment: can you give me your HTML

Comment: you want to change color of href in navbar according to background ? if i am not correct .give me any image telling your idea

Comment: I edited. you can see code snippet.